# Using UIReferenceLibraryViewController from Cocos2d (2.0)

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

Been struggling with this all day for some reason, hoping someone can shed some light on it.

I've set up a `CCLabelTTF` and added a touch handler for it, on touch end I want to look up the string value of that label in the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`. Here's what my attempt looks like (My game is in landscape mode which is why I'm attempting the 90degree rotation):

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"UIReferenceLibraryViewController")) {

                if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:word.Value] == YES)
                {
                     UIReferenceLibraryViewController *reference =
                    [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:word.Value];
                    reference.view.center = CGPointMake(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
                    reference.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f));

                    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:reference.view];
                }
            }
```

This **sort of** works. I click my label, the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` is shown (though it isn't rotated in landscape for some reason), and my definition shows up. When I click the "done" button in the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, however, my app crashes with an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Figure I'm missing something obvious here, but not sure what.

Any help is appreicated, of course.

Thanks
Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was declaring and instantiating the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` object inside a method in my class. I received an error when selecting the 'Done' button as my `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` object no longer existed at that point.
To solve the problem, I created a member variable within the class interface:

```
UIReferenceLibraryViewController *reference;
```

I then created a property with retain:

```
@property (retain) UIReferenceLibraryViewController *reference;
```

In the method when I wanted to present the dictionary screen in did used the following:

```
reference = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:cell.textLabel.text];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:reference.view];
```

I then released the reference object in the dealloc method.
Unfortunately, it no longer crashes but the 'Done' button does nothing now.

**Additional Information:** 
Ultimately I have my application working. My app adds a UITableView over a CCScene and allows the user to click a table view cell in order to look up the definition of the word within the cell.

In order to get this working I did the following:
Within my CCScene class (Game.m), I create a UITableView. I then create a UITableViewController class and set the UITableView dataSource and delegate to that new class.

```
myTableView.dataSource = myWordListViewController;
myTableView.delegate = myWordListViewController;
```

I then add the UITableView as a subview of the CCScene as follows;

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myTableView];
```

The CCScene class has a member variable (called delegate) that is an instance of my AppDelegate class. The AppDelegate class has a member variable that is an instance of the RootViewController.

```
RootViewController  *viewController;
```

So, now I have a UITableView presented to the user (on top of the CCScene). This table view contains a list of words. I now need to ensure the table view cells present the dictionary definition when clicked.

In my MyWordListViewController (UITableViewController) I ensure that the methods exist to allow this class to act as a data source and delegate for my table view.

```
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Also, when the user clicks a cell in the UITableView (that is a subview of CCSCENE), I want the dictionary to appear on top of the table view.

I am responding to the user click in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of MyWordListViewController. Since I added the table view as a subview of the CCScene (Game.m), I need to use the AppDelegate RootViewController that my CCScene is relying upon.

To do this, I added a member variable to MyWordListViewController that holds an instance of the AppDelegate class.

```
delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Now in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of MyWordListViewController, I can display the dictionary over the table view by relying upon the RootViewController variable within the AppDelegate class.

```
reference = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:cell.textLabel.text];

[delegate.viewController presentModalViewController:reference animated:YES];
```

It may not be the most eloquent solution but it works.